# var_dump only shows 1 array when upload more than 1 file

Tags: php, html, forms, upload, var-dump

i have a script that uploads images and then crops them. but when i use

```
    <input type="file" name="filename" multiple="multiple"/><br />
```

and then do a var_dump i only get 1 array instead of 'for example' 10 images.

My uploadform:

```
<form action="uploaded.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <hr>
    <input type="file" name="filename" multiple="multiple"/><br />
    <br /><br />
    <hr width="60" align="left">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

My code to see the uploades files:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_FILES);

die();
?>
```

when i upload 10 images. it only shows the first selected and prints out 1 array.

Please help!

Thanks

***EDIT: i think that i have to use a session for this. but how do i do that?***

Comment: BECAUSE `multiple="multiple"` is not implemented yet in all browsers

Comment: did you try to post the output of the field?? `$_POST['filename']` ??

Comment: That gives me an error

Comment: try var_dump($_POST);

Comment: and multiple="multiple" does work in chrome so that's not the problem. i got it working yesterday

Comment: var_dump($_POST); gives me an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as any other form element used more then once: `<input type="file" name="filename[]" multiple="multiple"/>`

Comment: Does not work? still shows 1 array when uploading 5 images now

Comment: Works here: one array, 5 elements (name/type/tmp_name/size/error), each with ***2*** items in it if uploading ***2*** files.

Comment: Hm yes maybe i explained it wrong. i get 1 array and 5 elements. but i need 5 arrays and 5 elements. for each image and array. you get it? does that have to do with an session_start();?

Comment: [that's just how it works](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php), altering the array to suit your needs is easy no? [see the first comment for instance](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240)

Comment: But yesterday i did it with sessions i guess. but someone else helped me with that so i don't really know how to do this.

Comment: File upload has zero to do with sessions, let me assure you of that. Unless you named multiple file input individually, this is _always_ how the raw `_FILES` array looks.

Comment: allright. i think it's a bit unclear for me. but another question is that i need to upload and crop more than 1 file after eachother when i upload several. but that's another question. thanks anyway